# Run code before all Airflow DAGs

Tags: airflow

I'm using the relatively new [airflow](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow) project. I have a bunch of DAGs written and running. Now I want to integrate a bug reporting service, so that if any code in any of the DAGs raises an exception, the information will be sent to a certain API. I can put the API call in the `on_failure_callback` of each DAG, but I need to execute an initializing line like `bug_reporter.init(bug_reporter_token)` that just needs to run once.

Is there a place in Airflow for initializing code? Right now I'm initializing the bug tracker at the beginning of every DAG definition file. This seems to be redundant, but I can't find a place to write a file that runs before the DAGs are defined. I've tried reading about [plugins](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/plugins.html), but it doesn't seem to be there.

Answer (score 4):

In your DAG definition file, instead of a DAG use your own subclass:

```py
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults
import bug_reporter

class DAGWithBugReporter(DAG):
    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(
        self,
        bug_reporter_token,
        *args, **kwargs):

        super(DAGWithBugReporter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        bug_reporter.init(bug_reporter_token)
```

Then in your dag definition:

```py
dag = DAGWithBugReporter(
    dag_id='my_dag',
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2017, 2, 26),
    bug_reporter_token=my_token_from_somewhere
)


t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='t1',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=my_callable,
    xcom_push=True,
    dag=dag)
```